# Canvas superimposed over video in IOS safari

Tags: ios, ipad, canvas, safari

Can you superimpose canvas over video in IOS safari (IPAD)? 
I tried adding text to the canvas but it does not show up on top of the video playing.

ON SAfari desktop it just works fine.

```
video_dom.addEventListener('play', function() {

        ctx_overlay.font = "bold 16px sans-serif";
        ctx_overlay.fillStyle="black"; 
        ctx_overlay.fillText("Video1 Video1 Video1", 200, 225);

}, false);

<video id="video-canvas-fancy"   loop autoplay loop height="640" width="965" style="position:absolute; top: 5; left: 5;"> 
<source src="http://severe-fire-901.heroku.com/videos/home.m3u8"> 
</video>
<canvas id="canvas-overlay" height="640" width="965" style="position:absolute; top: 10; left: 10;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give more details or a code example in the future.

You mean `<video>`? With absolute positioning you should be able to put anything over it.

If you can't for some (buggy) reason on IOS, you can always use a `<canvas>` to render the video (call `context.drawImage(video,0,0)` every x frames per second) and then either render stuff on top of that or on top of a second canvas.